# android: scale ImageView like telegram app

Tags: android, animation, imageview, telegram

How can I implement telegram app scaling `ImageView` effect?
telegram has rounded images for contacts. if I touch it in a amazing animation it gets scale and fill the screen. in animation transition image convert from circle to rectangle smoothly. I cannot find anyway to do this. I found libraries like shapedImageView but I have trouble with converting circle to rectangle smoothly.
[image]
[image]

my main challenge is the animation effect.

Comment: Can you find the answer? @ya-hoo

Comment: Salaam, Not yet

Comment: Salaam ;-), Can we find from telegram source code and use it? https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

Comment: Unfortunatly I couldn't find that

Answer (score 1):

The source code of telegram is available on github, so you can check it and see, how they implemented that.

Maybe it is also possible to achieve this effect with material transition animations, if you want to open picture in another activity/fragment. Have a look at this library, for example: [Material-Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations). I think you could try using shared elements.